# Bootstrap typhead.js doesn't highlight elements in auto-complete text-box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried every possible combination in order to get my elements highlighted on mouse-over event ( following the documentation of-course) after the drop down event of the auto-complete occurs, still haven't managed to get my elements highlighted.

I really don't know why is this such an issue.

CSS code which should highlight the elements:

```
    .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
    background-color: #0097CF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

JS code which allows elements being highlighted:

```
$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
```

HTML call:

```
<div id="the-basics">
  <input class="typeahead">
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really tell without a fiddle.

However the code you said responsible for the highlight is wrong.
It should be this one `.tt-suggestion:hover`

**Update**

Based from the fiddle given on the comment `.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor` does exist and styling it should work for the hover.

However if it doesn't work, you can try the solution below :

```
.tt-suggestion:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}
```

Comment: I' can't believe that the usual :hover works!!, Do you know why the tt-cursor does not?

Comment: @eugensunic Cool! Glad it helped. By looking at their examples and inspecting element, I can't see the `tt-cursor` as one of the classes. So `.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor ` doesn't exists that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @eugensunic Ok you're right, I won't argue about that. Could be because of the JS that's why I'm not able to see. I've seen similar issue you're having https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1174